# Tablet Keeps Shutting Down

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown

This has been going on for a couple of weeks..

I have this Windows 8.1 tablet, (32 bit Intel processor, 2G RAM, 64G disk with 720MB free space).

It shuts down soon after boot up.

As I power up, after a typical boot time and as the screens start to settle down, the screen will go blank except for the rotating circle and the words "shutting down.  If I do nothing, it will shut down.  I found that if I ctl-alt-del I can get the Task Manager and that will stop the shutdown for maybe 10 minutes and I can use the tablet.  Then it just shuts down.  No rotating circle.

In the ctl-alt-del mode, usually just before the shutdown I get a notification that  "Windows Security Service is not started, click to start".  If I click I get the message that "Windows Security Service cannot be started".  Then it shuts down.  If I don't click the notification the computer will stay up for a few minutes then shutdown.

I wanted to boot to safe mode but most of the methods fail.  One that I found that works is to power down during boot. If that happens 3 times the tablet will go to a special mode and by stepping through various options I can get it to reboot in safe mode with networking.  In safe mode it does not shutdown ever but there are a lot of things I can't do.  For example, no audio, no Windows Security, etc.

In safe mode I have tried things like:

```
SFC /SCANNOW with various options

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth  

chkdsk
```

Windows Defender, full scan, no threats found.

I tried a lot of other things, to numerous to remember.

Since it runs fine in safe mode but shuts down in Normal mode, it might be something that runs in Normal mode that is causing the problem. "Back in the day", I seem to remember ways to use safe mode to find the problem.  But I can't seem to find what those were.

Any ideas?

Comment: Examine the Event Viewer for useful messages.

Comment: I have tried that a few times.  I haven't been able to decipher the results.  I guess I need to study the tutorials in more detail.  I was hoping someone has a eureka moment for me.

Comment: Eureka doesn't come without information. Add to your post whatever information that you have, and we might be able to say more.

Comment: Check the startup applications, both *per* user and system. Use Autoruns to check *everything*.  You might also consider reinstalling an OS. If you can reinstall Windows 8.1, good. If not, test how the tablet works under Linux, e.g. Ubuntu Live, https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ , which can be run from a USB drive or SD/µSD card.

Comment: Dr.  I will take a look at Autoruns.  The only option this tablet has is to reset windows which it says will remove all programs and data.  That could be worse then my present state.  The tablet runs fine in Safe Mode so I can't see trying linux.  I made a USB bootable version of Windows defender but I can't make the tablet boot from the USB drive.  I can see the contents in file explorer but the tablet BIOS isn't accessible to force it to boot from USB.